# Conditional requirement setuptools/wheel

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

In Django 1.8, `django.contrib.formtools` [has been separated into a new package](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/formtools/) called `django-formtools`. When upgrading a project to the new Django version, changing the imports is enough. However for my package, I support all Django versions currently supported by Django. So now there's a conditional requirement when installing my package.

- Django >= 1.8, with django-formtools
- Django <= 1.7.99 without django-formtools

How to achieve this, with setuptools, and also remain compatible with wheel packaging?

Without the wheel requirement, the currently installed version of Django could be derived; and then `install_requires` could be dynamically adapted. However when installing using wheels, `setup.py` is not called (if I'm correct).